# Makefile static rule syntax explaination

Tags: makefile

This is a snippet of the makefile code example of static rule :

```
objects = foo.o bar.o

all: $(objects)

$(objects): %.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

what does this means like:

```
target : %.o : %.c
```

does this means that target : %.o and %.o : %.c explaining that all the dependency of the target would be generated by %.o rule and the recipe is applied on that and all the dependencies of %.o would be generated by %.c rule and recipe is applied?

Please somebody clarify it:

1.What are the static rule in makefile explain the syntax?

2.Does the recipe is applies on both the %.o and %.c rules?

3.Is it concatenation of **target : $(all).o** and **$(all).o : $(all).c** where **all** contains all the file names without any extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet:

```
objects = foo.o bar.o

all: $(objects)

$(objects): %.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

expands to (after expanding variables):

```
all: foo.o bar.o

foo.o bar.o: %.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This is a shorthand for writing:

```
foo.o: foo.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
bar.o: bar.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

So, in short, for each target in the target list apply the pattern and create a static rule for the result.

Comment: You cannot write `run: $(objects): %.o: %.c`.  That's too many colons.  A static pattern rule has exactly three parts separated by colons: a list of target names, a first pattern that must match each of the target names, and an optional second pattern which implies a prerequisite.  I don't really understand your question.